# Count() into a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [booking_id] => 1
        [booking_status] => confirmed
        [client_name] => Bale
        [client_firstname] => Gareth
        [days] => Array (
            [day_id] => 2016-11-23,2016-11-24
            [room_id] => 2
        )
    )
)
```

How can I get the number of item into `day_id` please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($data as $booking) {
    $sum += sizeof(explode(",",$booking["days"]["day_id"]));
}
```

Comment: Why I can not use the count function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce` to iterate through array items and get a final result. Take a look at [this](https://3v4l.org/MQ8H0):

```
function reduce_func($carry, $item){
    if (isset($item['days']) && !empty($item['days']['day_id'])){
        $carry += count(array_unique(array_filter(explode(',', $item['days']['day_id']))));
    }
    return $carry;
}

$result = array_reduce($arr, "reduce_func", 0);
```

**Update**

note that you can also provide a callback to the `array_filter` to filter out your desired entries to be counted, eg. regex checking each entry to be a valid date. Here's [PHP manual for `array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: Why I can not use the count function ?

Comment: `count()` only counts the first level elements of an array; also, it seems that you are interested in the counts of dates inside strings which `count()` can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum =0;
for ($count = 0; $count < count($data); $count++) {
    $booking = $data[$count];
    $day_ids = explode(",", $booking['days']['day_id'];
    $sum     = $sum + count($day_ids);
}
```